# Ruby ERB how to create list of mount points

Tags: ruby, erb, puppet

I am trying to use ERB templating to dynamically create a list of mount points for filesystems, to be monitored for disk usage by Nagios.  I am having trouble figuring out the exact syntax for ERB, I have it working in straight Ruby.

Here is what I have tried for ERB

```
 <% @str = `df -h`; @str.scan(/\/[\w\/]+$/){|m| -%><%= -p @m %><% unless m.match(/\/dev|\/proc/)};puts %>
```

Here is my code, and desired output working in the Ruby CLI:

```
ruby -e '
str = `df -h`
str.scan(/\/[\w\/]+$/){|m| print "-p #{m} " unless m.match(/\/dev|\/proc/)};puts'
-p /net -p /home -p /Network/Servers <-- Output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **you don't need to run those in the template**. You probably have some ruby code lauching the template (like a Rails controller or a Sinatra class). You can put your code there, and store the output to show in the template (example assuming rails).

Second, **you don't want to use print or puts** (as those would output toward the terminal, not the template), but to store the output in a variable.

The controller:

```
class MountPointsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @output = ""
    str = `df -h`
    str.scan(/\/[\w\/]+$/){|m| output << "-p #{m} " unless m.match(/\/dev|\/proc/)};output << "\n"
  end
end
```

The template is then as simple as (note the '<%=' that means "output the result in the template):

```
<%= @output %>
```

Even if I would recommend against, here is a sample with all the code in the template:

```
<% @output = "" %>
<% str = `df -h` %>
<% str.scan(/\/[\w\/]+$/){|m| output << "-p #{m} " unless m.match(/\/dev|\/proc/)};output << "\n" %>
<%= @output %>
```

Comment: I am using puppet, so the template is my best bet at generating the string, otherwise I would need to download a script to run that code locally or use Facter.

Comment: Do you have access to any place to put code in before rendering the template? While workable, templates are no great place for commands like your sample. The pure erb sample should work, still.

Comment: I could use a fact, a machine specific variable.  Then reference the fact as a top scope variable.  Thats probably best practice here.  Either way, thanks this is perfect.

Comment: I just realized, I can't do this the ERB way anyhow, I need a fact, because ERB df- h is evaluated on the Puppet Server, not client.  FYI, when I tried it, the 3rd line output instances requires @output to work.

Comment: I moved the code into a fact, now I want the ERB to use the fact variable if it's defined, otherwise use a default value.  How would I do that? `<%= @output if @output else @output = '-p /tmp -p /boot -p /home' %>`  Something like that?

Comment: I tried `<% defined?(@mountpoints) ? @mountpoints : '-p /var -p /oac -p / -p /home -p /tmp -p /boot' %><%= @mountpoints %>`

Comment: `<% @mountpoints ||=  '-p /var -p /oac -p / -p /home -p /tmp -p /boot' %>` is the standard 'ruby way', a shortcut for `@mountpoints = @mountpoints || ...`

Comment: This should be a new question. Anyway, since Puppet variables may not have a value that is falsish (I'm looking at you, empty string), you can usually use this pattern in the template: `<%= ( @mountpoint && ! @mountpoint.empty?) ? @mountpoint : 'default value' %>'. Beware of numbers, but Puppet 3.x variables should not take those.